# How to make Data REST repository method Asynchronous

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Is it possible to make a repository exposed as rest resource via the `@RepositoryRestResource` annoation Async? Or in other words, I want the save, find etc mehtods to be async and the `ResponseEntityController` also process these as async calls?

If I simply mark the repository as sync my POST request fails because this method on `ResponseEntityController` would not process async persist calls for a repository

```
private ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport> createAndReturn(Object domainObject, RepositoryInvoker invoker,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler, boolean returnBody) {

    publisher.publishEvent(new BeforeCreateEvent(domainObject));
    Object savedObject = invoker.invokeSave(domainObject);
    publisher.publishEvent(new AfterCreateEvent(savedObject));

    Optional<PersistentEntityResource> resource = Optional
            .ofNullable(returnBody ? assembler.toFullResource(savedObject) : null);

    HttpHeaders headers = headersPreparer.prepareHeaders(resource);
    addLocationHeader(headers, assembler, savedObject);

    return ControllerUtils.toResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED, headers, resource);
}
```

here's my repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "companies", collectionResourceRel = "companies")
public interface CompanyRepository extends CrudRepository<Company, Long> {

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(Company entity);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void deleteById(Long id);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void deleteAll();

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends Company> entities);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found is to stick to Spring Data JPA and write your own HATEOAS controllers returning CompletableFutrues which call Services that assemble HATEAOS Resource(s) from values returned by JPA repository. The controller to Service and Service to JPA repository calls can then be asynchronous using Thread pool executor or Concurrent executor etc.